# Clarification of BlackBerry Messenger QRCode format.

Tags: php, blackberry, qr-code

I'm currently developing a web app that needs to generate a QRCode from a user submitted BlackBerry PIN.

I'm able to generate QRCodes using PHP, but I don't understand the format that BBM reads from QRCodes which is: bbm:[PIN][some digits][display name]

What are the digits after the [PIN]? Are they just some random numbers or a checksum?
Are there any additional things that can be put into the QRCode?
I tried googling for hours, but found nothing.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you got any example bbm qr codes, that we can decode and work out what they mean?
Also, post some added information about each qr code.

Comment: Try this link: http://www.sparqcode.com/static/maestro, and select contact > blackberry pin.
If you then read the generated qrcode, you would get the format I mentioned. Thanks

Comment: Looks like an hex code or CRC32 of something made from the pin. The generator here fills with zeroes: http://azonmobile.com/qrcode-generator

Answer (score 0):

I first thought the same thing as @Mister Smith but tried a few different PINs and contact info and then tried this in a few different BBM QR code generators. The one thing which seems to be held in common with all of them is bbm:12345678 where 12345678 is the PIN. What follows (in my case 42ec1444 on one reader, and 42ec1444aaaa where the username of aaaa was input) does not appear to be required.  It is definitely not a checksum as 42ec1444 remained regardless of what username or PIN I selected on a few of the online QR generators for BBM QR codes.